# How to monitor xml file for (add - edit - delete ) node(s)

Tags: c#, xml, filesystemwatcher

in my Solution i have two projects (Windows Service and WPF to mange the service) 
and i have a sitting file (XML) that service use
What i ask about is :

i want to know when the user make any change in the XML file with out restart the service 
and know  What is the xml node(s) that has changed

I have searched a lot and found that the solution is through [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when
>   a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

but how i know What is the xml node(s) that has changed

thanks

Comment: How do you read configuration XML? Do you use XPath or do you have some Settings class that you serialize/deserialize to XML?

Comment: it is simple xml file and i use Linq to xml

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a copy of the original XML and then run a compare when the FileSystemWatcher triggers. Have a look at [Efficient algorithm for comparing XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343667/efficient-algorithm-for-comparing-xml-nodes) for a suggestion on comparing XML nodes.

File watcher example

```
String folderLocation = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FOLDER_LOCATION"].ToString();

            _watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
            _watcher.Path = folderLocation;
            _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Size;
            _watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileChanged);
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            String file = e.FullPath;
...
```