# Is there an XML asserts for NUnit?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, nunit

Does NUnit support (perhaps by using a third party libraries) a smart comparison for XML data.

Let's say we need to compare two xml files - the simplest way would be to compare xml content using the no-case sensitive string comparison, but that would only work in a trivial cases.

Is there any library around which could simplify xml comparison - e.g. some kind of XmlAssert?

The functionality I am after - "having a two xml files, compare these nodes (because they are important) and ignore the rest".

### Similar questions

- [What is the best way to compare XML files for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299553/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-xml-files-for-equality)
- [How would you compare two XML Documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167946/how-would-you-compare-two-xml-documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is work on porting [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to .Net.  I've only used the Java version, and don't know how complete the port is.  It may not be ready for prime-time...

Comment: Thanks, going give it a try. Last release is dated back to Apr-2009, is it alive project?

Comment: Last commit is pretty recent though - that's a good sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same kind of tool for .NET and found this: [Jolt.NET](http://jolt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Jolt.Testing.Assertions.XML.Adaptors). Going to try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself at this point, but fluentassertions.com has a library addon for NUnit and other testing frameworks that allows for this type of assertion. Might be useful to someone.

```
xDocument.Should()
.HaveElement("child")
.Which.Should()
.BeOfType<XElement>()
.And.HaveAttribute("attr", "1");
```

Comment: I've now tried fluent assertions myself, and it does perform the exact test the original poster requested very nicely, even if my answer wasn't spot on.