# How can I use XMLDiffPatch.dll in Access vba?

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, dll

I downloaded XMLDiffPatch.dll from Microsoft site and ran the install.
The dll seems to have been registered - but when I try to reference it from Access vba tools menu, I get an error:

```
Can't add a reference to the specified file
```

I wish to be able to call XMLDiff and XMLPatch from vba - how can I achieve that?
Why can I not reference the dll from vba?

PS: I would not mind a solution that offers a java jar instead; actually I would prefer that. But I have not been able to find an XMLDiffPatch jar on the web.

Comment: [Link to XMLDiffPatch sample code in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa302294.aspx) and [Similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167946/how-would-you-compare-two-xml-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments: Link to XMLDiffPatch sample code in C# and Similar question on SO