# Compare two Xml Documents in Silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight

I need to compare two xml documents for equality, just as described in this post: [How would you compare two XML Documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167946/how-would-you-compare-two-xml-documents)
The Xml Diff API would be fantastic, but unfortunately it can't be referenced in Silverlight.

Anybody know of a similar solution for silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without the use of a library, I would - employ a depth first search on the source document, associate an xpath with each **leaf** encountered and place that xpath with it's associated value on a stack. (most likely some xpath custom class for path and value). (the option of a dictionary is there too. :) ). Once the depth first search is completed, I would pop each element of the stack off, execute the X-path on the destination document, and once a disparity in the xpath values are encountered - consider the documents unequal.
Just a theoretical suggestion.