# C# Compare two XML files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a sync program in C# that should be able to sync folders and file between a server and multiple clients. The problem is that only what is on the server should be sent to the clients.
I want to compare two XML files and get the result in a new XML file.
I want to be able to see what is the differences between file 1 and 2 and only get what file 2 is missing from file 1. Something like shown below.
XML file 1 - XML file 2 = XML file 3

XML file 1 - This is a view of all the files and sub-folders

```
<Sync>
  <file name="file1.exe" md5="301977135631682077322272102379711510898" />
  <file name="file2.gif" md5="198293138141481761522471841122211715365100" />
  <file name="file3.docx" md5="2421394619714515234127212777726185214112245"/>
  <file name="file4.docx" md5="192234220151104120192442391857158145211131" />
  <file name="file5.txt" md5="168303710116177182411519715713816617416674" />
  <file name="file6.bmp" md5="1792011292231121792151655125106213101156216" />
  <file name="file7.txt" md5="33187821621591371126952143181189193108" />
  <file name="file8.ini" md5="2282341791393124126722550279185251209139" />
  <folder name="folder1">
    <file name="file9.reg" md5="17553712523921412874140137119129165185219" />
    <folder name="folder2">
      <file name="file10.png" md5="13197182105223023710241762821170145139202" />
      <file name="file11.docx" md5="205130242851746130180151132127731757621530" />
    </folder>
  </folder>
</Sync>
```

XML file 2 - This is a view of all another path of files and sub-folders

```
<Sync>
  <file name="file1.exe" md5="301977135631682077322272102379711510898" />
  <file name="file7.txt" md5="33187821621591371126952143181189193108" />
  <file name="file8.ini" md5="2282341791393124126722550279185251209139" />
  <folder name="folder1">
    <file name="file9.reg" md5="17553712523921412874140137119129165185219" />
      <file name="file13.docx" md5="205130242851746130180151132127731757621530" />
    <folder name="folder2">
      <file name="file11.docx" md5="205130242851746130180151132127731757621530" />
      <file name="file12.docx" md5="205130242851746130180151132127731757621530" />
    </folder>
  </folder>
</Sync>
```

XML file 3 - This is a view of all the files and sub-folders file 1 is missing

```
<Sync>
  <file name="file2.gif" md5="198293138141481761522471841122211715365100" />
  <file name="file3.docx" md5="2421394619714515234127212777726185214112245"/>
  <file name="file4.docx" md5="192234220151104120192442391857158145211131" />
  <file name="file5.txt" md5="168303710116177182411519715713816617416674" />
  <file name="file6.bmp" md5="1792011292231121792151655125106213101156216" />
  <folder name="folder1">
    <folder name="folder2">
      <file name="file10.png" md5="13197182105223023710241762821170145139202" />
    </folder>
  </folder>
</Sync>
```

Comment: what is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Buy a copy of Beyond Compare 4.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what you are working on.  We're right here when you get stuck and want to post some code that you need help with.

Comment: just flatten ur structure and store the file path with the filename....so easy that way

Comment: Use Left Outer Join Linq Method : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @Dan Andrews, hiroprotagonist, Tobias Knauss - if you think this question is duplicate of another question, just mark it as duplicate. Online rant has even less value than duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare XML fragments & return differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482514/compare-xml-fragments-return-differences)

Comment: @vittore Did I say something that led you to believe that I thought this question was a duplicate or are you just trying to be efficient by sending a rant to all of us in one comment?  I thanked the op for telling us what he's working on - which is intent of his post (does it read differently to you?).  I also let him know that should he have a problem, we're anxiously waiting to hear it.  Is it stands, there is no question mark in the post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) who is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows. he can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way of doing this is by using [diffgrams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is example [Compare XML fragments & return differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482514/compare-xml-fragments-return-differences)

Key code:

```
var result = new XDocument();
var writer = result.CreateWriter();

var diff = new Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch.XmlDiff();    
diff.Compare(node1, node2, writer);

writer.Flush(); 
writer.Close();
```