# How to interpret the output of XmlDiff

Tags: c#, xml

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482514/compare-xml-fragments-return-differences?lq=1), it is described how to get the differences of two XML files using Microsoft [XmlDiffPatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx). But it is doesn't say how I can interpret the output.

I have two xml files:

```
<MN>
   <MN>
      <PUNC>
         <w>#</w>
      </PUNC>
      <MN>
         <N>
            <N>
               <w>مسعود</w>
            </N>
            <N>
               <w>شجاعی</w>
            </N>
         </N>
         <N>
            <w>طباطبایی</w>
         </N>
      </MN>
   </MN>
   <PUNC>
      <w>#</w>
   </PUNC>
</MN>
```

And

```
<S>
   <MN>
      <PUNC>
         <w>#</w>
      </PUNC>
      <MN>
         <N>
            <w>مسعود</w>
         </N>
         <N>
            <w>شجاعی</w>
         </N>
         <N>
            <w>طباطبایی</w>
         </N>
      </MN>
      <PUNC>
         <w>#</w>
      </PUNC>
   </MN>
</S>
```

The result of XmlCompare is:

[image]

Now I want to get the number of `removes`, `changes`, `adds` and `moves` from this output. How can I do this?