# .NET XML Comparaison with type of modification

Tags: c#, xml

I need to compare in .NET 2 XML documents with the same schema.
I also need to add if the node has been updated/deleted/added.

**Exemple:**
doc1:

```
<Root>
    <Node1>
        <Node11>abc</Node11>
        <Node12>def</Node12>
        <Node13>dhi</Node13>
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
    </Node2>
</Root>
```

doc2:

```
<Root>
    <Node1>
        <Node12>ABCdef</Node12>
        <Node13>dhi</Node13>
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node21>dhi</Node21>
    </Node2>
</Root>
```

result:

```
<Root>
    <Node1>
        <Node11 Info='DELETED'>abc</Node11>
        <Node12 Info='UPDATED'>def</Node12>
        <Node13 Info='NO CHANGE'>dhi</Node13>
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node21 Info='ADDED'>dhi</Node21>
    </Node2>
</Root>
```

Does someone have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: What is _your_ idea? What have you come up with so far? What are your "showstoppers"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you compare two XML Documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167946/how-would-you-compare-two-xml-documents)