# How can I compare the nodes/root nodes and the attributes of 2 different XML files in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

My strategy is:

1. Use XDocument.load() to read the XML files
2. Create an array with the root nodes of interest
3. if the root nodes (for one XML-file) does not exist in the other XML-file, create a new XML file and paste the node (incl. elements and attributes) in there.
4. Save the new document.

Are there any easier strategies than mine?

Do you have any advices of how I can solve this?

Comment: Use a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tool?

Comment: Your question seems very broad.  Did you see [How would you compare two XML Documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/167946/3744182)?  Do the answers there work for you?  If not, why not?  What have you tried so far?  What do you mean by *array with the root nodes of interest*, can you share a [mcve] that narrows your question?